# How can I remove the DRM from PDFs so that I can read them in Google Play Books

Tags: pdf, google, ebooks, drm, calibre

Google Play Books is my reader app of choice for Android.  I like that I can highlight and take notes, and that I have a pipeline for those notes to get them in to an Anki deck (amongst other things).

Unfortunately, some books don't allow me to highlight text, and when I zoom in, it appears to be rendering the text as an image, because it becomes pixelated.  This is despite the fact that xreader can see the PDF as text just fine, and in there I can highlight it, and copy it and so on.  My assumption is that Play is respecting some kind of DRM, where xreader just doesn't care to enforce that.

How can I strip out this DRM, so that Play will let me treat text PDFs as text?

[This](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/dialogue-threeeasy.pdf) is the file I've been using to test with.  xreader sees it as text, Play does not.  I've tried following instructions to remove DRM using calibre, involving a plugin.  It's hard to tell if that's worked because opening document from calibre uses xreader anyway, which never had problems in the first place.  From there I've tried saving, or exporting, and then uploading to Play, with no effect.  I've also tried converting it to epub, and then uploading.  I've tried websites that claim to do this, but they didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you asking here?   No OS or release is mentioned.

Comment: I thought this being an Ubuntu forum made that implicit.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall you would be surprised at how often people come here asking questions that have nothing to do with computers, let alone Ubuntu Linux. For what you describe, it doesn't sound like DRM at all. You are looking at a literal image that is wrapped in a PDF. I see this sort of thing all the time with textbooks and it's incredibly annoying. If you'd like to test this, try some of the options at [SmallPDF](https://smallpdf.com), which has some of the better PDF manipulation tools available.

Comment: Ubuntu has multiple products, some are limited to *snap* only packages, others can use multiple types of packages, let alone many users trying to use the site for non-Ubuntu OSes.  This also isn't a forum, but Q&A site, https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the Ubuntu Forums.